# Let's say you have a graph defined by $f(t) = 2t + 8 $ if $t \le 3$ $ f(t) = 2 $ if $t \gt 3 $ what is the area?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

So, I have two functions which let me reiterate

$ f(t) = -2t + 8$

if $0 \leq $ t $ \leq 3 $

$f(t) =  2 $ if $t \gt 3$

Now, what this looks like is a downward slope from y = 8 and x = 0 that stops reducing at about t = 3 and every f(t) becomes 2.

When I solve for the Area of 2 or A(2) I do the following calculations :

$\frac{1}{2}(2)(6)$ The height at t = 2 is exactly 6, so my answer should be 6. I look at the back of the book and find that the answer is 12.
I have no idea why the answer is 12.

I then look at A(5) which should be the area of the first piece of the graph. (Which for arguments sake, we're going to say is 12) and then add that to the area of the base and the height since the remainder of the graph is a rectangle we do not need to do the base times height formula.

So, it becomes an interval of [3,6] which is 6-3 = 3 times the height which is 2.
This should just be 3*2 based on my understanding, which is 6. So, 12 + 6 is just 18.

I turn to the back of the book and find 21. I'm kind of lost here, please help me.

Comment: **Clarification requested:** "When I solve for the Area of 2 or A(2) I do the following calculations :" What precisely is $A(2)$ supposed to signify?  If you have a function $f(x)$, and you are interested in the area *underneath* $f(x)$ (to express it informally) in the interval $[a,b]$, then you express this as $\int_a^b f(x)dx.$  Before I can respond to your question, I need to understand what significance that you intend by the expression $A(2)$.

Comment: Area of t = 2. . . .I wrote it repeatedly in my question. Furthermore, I am in the beginning of a calculus book, I am not on Integration yet and therefore not allowed to use it.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.  To clarify the area that you are interested in, you need to clarify **both ends** of the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: $f(2)=8-4=4$ and the area under the curve between $x=0,2$ is a trapezium with parallel side lengths $f(0)=8,f(2)=4$ and thus the area is $1/2(2)(8+4)=12$. For area between $x=0,6$ note that between $x=0,3$ the area of the trapezium is $1/2(3)(f(0)+f(3))=15$ and between $x=3,6$ the area is a rectangle as you observed with the area $3*2=6$, giving the sum as $21$.

Comment: Ooooh, so I'm supposed to use the area of a trapezium rather than the area of a triangle.

Comment: No, at the point in the query where you state :"When I solve for the Area of 2 or A(2)..." it is not obvious.  It is only later in the query that a mathSE reviewer (if they are so inclined) can *reverse-engineer* your intended meaning.  The point here is to clarify the question **up front**.

Comment: I do agree with @user2661923, there is a large number of typos in your question and you don't specify what "area of $2,A(2)$" means. It is actually the area under the curve between $x=0,2$. It is advised to reread and verify your post once you type it out.

Comment: It is also advised that once someone requests clarification, that you (again) re-read your query and (at least consider) editing your query after the fact to make it crystal clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

[image]

An area is defined between two limit values of $x$.

The area for any range is simply given by high-school calculus:

$$A = \int\limits_{x = x_l}^{x_u} f(x)\ dx$$

Comment: Let me clarify, I only need t going from 0 and onward.

Comment: Also, two limit values of x? So I can't use 1/2 base * height like normal?

Comment: Depends where the base *is*, of course.  Try $-10< x< -9$ versus $4 < x < 5$, for instance.

Comment: So, it would be the same formula 1/2 (b * h). But, our height changes. Since t = -10 would get you -12 and t = --9 would get you -10, you would do $\frac{1}{2}(1)*(-10-12) which is -11, right? Because our heights have different placements, we end up having to change the equation a bit to accommodate it. But, what can I do to formalize that a bit more?